# I can't get all the files in a directory with GetFiles method

Tags: vb.net

I tried to use `Directory.Getfiles` but it wont get all the files in a directory. Files are in .txt format
 Here is my code in the `Form_Load`:

```
Public SourceDir As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Source\"
If Not Directory.Exists(SourceDir) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(SourceDir)
    End If
Dim Files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir )


    For Each File In Files
        Dim Lines() As String
        Dim StockList As List(Of ListViewItem) = New List(Of ListViewItem)
        Dim StockItem As ListViewItem
        MsgBox(File)

        Lines = IO.File.ReadAllText(File).Split(New String() {ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For j = 0 To Lines.Length - 1 Step 8

            StockItem = New ListViewItem(Lines(j))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 1))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 2))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 3))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 4))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 5))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 6))
            StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 7))
            listHouse.Items.Add(StockItem)
        Next
    Next
```

it only shows one of the files and that's all!

Comment: Which files is it not getting?

Comment: Which files dont you get? Is there a specific type? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It's not a specific files. All the files are .txt format

Comment: Are the files directly in that "Source" folder?  Or are they under some sub-folder?  There's nothing special about the ones it's not finding?

Comment: They are directly in that folder. It finds the first file for example if there is three files with name "1R.txt", "2R.txt" and "3R.txt" it only can read "1R.txt" and when I delete that one it reads only "2R.txt" and so on!

Comment: Is this placed in a try block? Because "For j = 0 To Lines.Length - 1 Step 8" this is dangerous. And I somewhat expect you to have a Index exception.

Comment: Agreed.  It's most likely throwing an exception.  You should step through the code in the debugger.  See what the value of the `Files` array is, and see where the execution path goes after processing the first file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but first you should just see if files() has the full list before you continue on to reading the files.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SourceDir As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Source\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(SourceDir) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(SourceDir)
    End If
    Dim Files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir)


    For Each File In Files
        Dim Lines() As String
        Dim StockList As List(Of ListViewItem) = New List(Of ListViewItem)
        Dim StockItem As ListViewItem
        Lines = IO.File.ReadAllText(File).Split(New String() {ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        StockItem = New ListViewItem(Lines(0))
        If Lines.Length > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Lines.Length - 1
                StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j))
            Next
        End If
        listHouse.Items.Add(StockItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` using following way.

```
Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```